# Angular ngRoute conditional .when()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I'd like to implement a conditional .when(), like this:

```
.when('/abc', {
     // if MyService.allow == true
     template: '<myDirec></myDirec>'
     // else
     redirectTo: '/'
})
```

My `/abc` route shall be like "secured" by a variable hold in one of my services, in a stateful manner. So I want to set this very state somewhere else to true/false and the next time the user tries to get to /abc he will be served conditionally.

**How can I achieve this?** - with as few 3rd-party dependencies as possible

What I tried and read about:
 - Simply injecting my Service in .config, which I learnt is not possible
 - Read about using a provider as they can be injected. But can I use them like I use my service?
 - template and templateUrl accept a function, but this didn't really help me

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the $routeChangeStart event. It's fired when the url is changed and takes current and next as arguments something like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
  if (next === 'abc') // do something;
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be a little bit more precise, I'm kind of a angular beginner :/ Where shall I put that? Not in the config part, right? In a `run` configuration? Doesn't seem to work, can change URL and not even a console.log triggering.. And $rootScope got a capital S, correct?

Comment: $routechangestart is an angular built in event that's fired when the url route changes. You can probably find this in the docs for $rootscope. I'd suggest putting this code in the controller that's active when the route changes or even better doing it in a service and injecting into your controller

Comment: Alright I got it working. I put this watcher (is it a watcher or kind of?) into my service which holds the bool variable. But one thing: I edited your code, there were 3 code errors in it, now it can be copied and pasted if anyone needs it. Thanks for your help!